# Display works weird after installing new kernel

Tags: 14.04, kernel, display

I've downloaded and installed linux kernel 4.3.2 over 3.19 on Ubuntu 14.04. Config was made with xconfig (I've changed only compression to xz). When i boot with new kernel, everything's fine, but then I got this: http://i73.fastpic.ru/big/2015/1227/0f/d36655a87fd228b3f48cb64281e4dd0f.jpg
Still, Ubuntu seems to work fine: http://i73.fastpic.ru/big/2015/1227/91/864bec5d495d585896bb4e029a5a5691.jpg
And no sign of error on screenshot, mouse clicks objects behind an artifact.
What I should do?
Graphics provided by IGMA 950.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in booting with grub using `gfxmode keep`; changing it to `text` or removing this line solved the problem.